# EMR setting config json results in conf file not being created

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

Normally, there is a `spark-defaults.conf` file located in `/etc/spark/conf` after I create a spark cluster on EMR.

If I provide no custom configs, you'll find `spark-defaults.conf` sitting happily in the conf directory:

```
[hadoop@ip-x-x-x-x ~]$ ls -la /etc/spark/conf/
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  4 08:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  4 07:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  987 Jul 26 21:56 docker.properties.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1105 Jul 26 21:56 fairscheduler.xml.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2373 Oct  4 07:42 hive-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2024 Oct  4 07:42 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2025 Jul 26 21:56 log4j.properties.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7239 Oct  4 07:42 metrics.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7239 Jul 26 21:56 metrics.properties.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  865 Jul 26 21:56 slaves.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2680 Oct  4 08:08 spark-defaults.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1292 Jul 26 21:56 spark-defaults.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1563 Oct  4 07:42 spark-env.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3861 Jul 26 21:56 spark-env.sh.template
```

Following the instructions from http://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html , i'm trying to add a jar to the driver and executor extraClassPath properties.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.driver.extraClassPath": ":/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/home/hadoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar",
      "spark.executor.extraClassPath": ":/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/home/hadoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    },
    "Configurations":[

    ]
  }
]
```

I dont see any errors upon creation of the cluster, but the `spark-defaults.conf` file never appears when I add this config.

[image]

and here's an `ls` showing that the file does not exist in the filesystem:

```
[hadoop@ip-x-x-x-x ~]$ ls -la /etc/spark/conf/
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  4 08:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  4 07:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  987 Jul 26 21:56 docker.properties.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1105 Jul 26 21:56 fairscheduler.xml.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2373 Oct  4 07:42 hive-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2024 Oct  4 07:42 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2025 Jul 26 21:56 log4j.properties.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7239 Oct  4 07:42 metrics.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7239 Jul 26 21:56 metrics.properties.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  865 Jul 26 21:56 slaves.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1292 Jul 26 21:56 spark-defaults.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1563 Oct  4 07:42 spark-env.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3861 Jul 26 21:56 spark-env.sh.template
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just tested this on EMR and the problem is that you have a `:` in front of your classpath specification:

```
"spark.driver.extraClassPath": ":/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/...
```

needs to be

```
"spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/....
```

Note that AWS also puts things on the classpath by setting `extraClassPath` and that stuff you specify in `extraClassPath` will *overwrite* and not append to that. In other words, you should make sure that your `spark.xxx.extraClassPath` includes the stuff that AWS puts there by default.

Comment: I'm going through all this trouble to config with their existing string + mine because setting extraClassPath gets overwritten when I use `--spark.driver.extraClassPath` upon submit. Its such a bummer that it doesn't simply append in the first place. thank you for checking this out. also.. the leading colon is how EMR sets the string to begin with when I first look at the config

Comment: You aren't really doing anything wrong. However, Glennie is correct about the initial ":" being the cause of the problem. This is actually a very weird bug in the parsing and handling of the configuration classifications provided by the customer, and it results in the file failing to be created. I think this issue might be fixed in the latest emr-4.x release (emr-4.8.0) but not yet in the EMR-5.x line. If it's not fixed in emr-4.8.0, it will be fixed iin the next emr-4.x and emr-5.x releases.

Comment: @JonathanKelly very insightful, how did you come upon this information?

Comment: oh. haha we may have met, actually.